# Drupal 7 permission to editor type user showing certain admin menus

Tags: 7

I have created the editor type user and now I would like to show only content menu and block menu to show in administrator area. But even I have change the permssion but top admin menu is not showing. if i assigned the admistrator role to editor user whole administrator menu showes up. but I only want to show certain options in top menu.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for being stupid. if you give the rights to "toolbar" in permission area. toolbar will show up :) you can also use [Content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access)

Comment: Have you answered your own question?  If so mark it as the accepted answer otherwise you might find other people trying to answer...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Menu per role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module could help yo set up exactly the type of menu you want for your role.